# PHP Parse error in Magento 2 on CentOS 7

Tags: magento2

a website on centos 7 ec2 instance and get the following error

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in
>   /dir/www/html/app/code/Webkul/Marketplace/Block/Collection.php on line
>   145

Although this line doesn't contain foreach , and when I go to the project directory I found all files and directories deleted and only **app** folder with **code** and  **design** folder. When i get into **code** folder I found only **webkul** folder.

**Note:** that's happend after stop and start the instance

So what's the problem ?

Comment: you have to check someone call this class directly in theme?

Comment: post your code of **`Collection.php`** , it might be an array issue or a code issue like a missing semi-colon

Comment: Delete the generated/metadata, generated/code, pub/static/frontend pub/static/adminhtml, pub/static/__cache, var/cache, var/page_cache, var/view_preprocessed and then flush the cache and run di:compile, static content deploy and test it again.